# How to create a row in spring boot at runtime if it's not existed

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was using the @ManyTOMany to function but the other doesn't have details provided by the id so may I know how to insert the row automatically at runtime if I give the id to it with default constraints?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about your requirement but you can use @PostConstruct Annotation to do stuff at runtime.

```
 @PostConstruct
    public void checkData(){
        // Do something ...
    }
```